# Can you use DBeaver to manage SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, dbeaver

All, I'm very new to DBeaver. I've installed the Lite edition and am liking it for the most part. However, I'm missing many of the SQL Server administration bits that I'm used to seeing in SQL Server Management Studio such as SQL Server Agent Jobs, Security, etc. Am I just missing this option, do I need a version other than Lite, or is this just functionality that does not exist in DBeaver?

[image]

Comment: Agent is a very specific tool to SQL Server, where as DBeaver is designed to be generic. There might be add=ons available for it, but recommendations for such things are off topic for [so]. Why don't want to use the tools designed for the RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Generally, JDBC tools only provide access to tables, views, etc. Any internals that are extracted into separate GUI elements in management studio would likely be stored in the dbo system tables, if anywhere

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've been using SSMS for many years and, for the most part, it is a solid tool and does exactly what it's supposed to. However, it lacks a lot of the functionality that DBeaver has such as easily storing executed queries for later review, quickly creating ER diagrams and more. Generally, in the short time I've been using DBeaver, I've found it much more efficient to do many things in my daily job. Additionally, in my job, I'm working with SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc., often all in the same day. I'd rather have 1 database tool versus 3.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using multiple tools, @FergmanTN . I swap between ADS and SSMS all the time.

Comment: If you want a car that gets good gas mileage at top speeds while towing a barge, well, good luck. :-) Most of us use multiple tools because no tool does it all (never mind well). As for storing and reviewing executed queries, look into Query Store or a monitoring tool.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that's why I'm looking at getting a new electric truck..no gas and will tow a huge amount. ;-) More seriously, I've been using multiple tools for years such as SSMS, PGAdmin, Teradata SQL Assistant (or Queryman), Toad, SQL Workbench, etc. so I'm very used to that. I was just hoping that maybe, finally someone created one that will do 95% of what need in one tool. I think DBeaver may be that tool for me because it allows me to query multiple RDBMS's without changing tools. I'll just have to keep the others around for their specific functionality that DBeaver doesn't serve...yet.

Comment: Also, to be more specific about storing executed queries, I was not looking for the "back end" solution to do performance tuning, etc. I'm looking for something that stores, in my app, the queries I've executed so I can go back and grab one quickly to re-run without having to store it in a text file somewhere.

Comment: Plan Explorer does that last bit quite well. Again, nobody is ever going to create a tool that does 100% of the things you want, and does it all well. Trying to whittle down to exactly one tool is an unrealistic pipe dream IMHO. Maybe the answer is going to DBeaver support and making a business case for them adding functionality like this (or at least they can tell you if it's possible for you to implement some kind of plug-in or add-on yourself). It's unlikely your peers here can solve the problem.